# Checking for successful S3 copy operation?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I'm trying to implement a move operation using the Amazon S3 Java API.

The problem I am having is that the [`CopyObjectResult`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/CopyObjectResult.html) object returned by the [`AmazonS3Client.copyObject`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#copyObject%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method doesn't seem to have a clear indicator about wiether the operation was successful or not.

Given that after this operation I am going to be deleting a file, I'd want to make sure that the operation was successful.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that the method can fail without throwing an exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing,

```
def s3 = createS3Client(credentials)
def originalMeta = s3.getObjectMetadata(originalBucketName, key)
s3.copyObject(originalBucketName, key, newBucketName, newKey)
def newMeta = s3.getObjectMetadata(newBucketName, newKey)

// check that md5 matches to confirm this operation was successful
return originalMeta.contentMD5 == newMeta.contentMD5
```

Note that this is Groovy code, but it is extremely similar to how the Java code would work.

I don't like having to make two additional operations to check the metadata, so if there is anyway to do this more efficiently let me know.

Comment: This is pretty similar to what I recently did with the PHP API. I'd capture the originals etag, copy, compare original etag to copied etag, if match, delete original.

Comment: Historical note, following up on Dan's comment: It appears that the system for generating etags changes when a multipart upload is used as opposed to a regular upload, so comparison by MD5 might be the better approach.

Comment: Since S3 doesn't have immediate consistency, wouldn't this method occasionally show that the object hasn't been copied even though it has?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can just use CopyObjectResult object's [getETag method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/) to confirm that, after created, it has a valid ETag, as was made in the CopyObjectRequest setETag method.

> getETag
>
> `public String getETag()` Gets the ETag value for the new object that
>   was created in the associated CopyObjectRequest. Returns: The ETag
>   value for the new object. See Also: setETag(String) setETag
>
> `public void setETag(String etag)` 
>   Sets the ETag value for the new
>   object that was created from the associated copy object request.
>   Parameters: etag - The ETag value for the new object. See Also:
>   getETag()

Always trust the data.

Been a year since I did a similar function with the Amazon PhP SDK a couple years ago, but it should work.

Comment: This is probably just me being unfamiliar with S3, but what explicitly would I check for on the etag string?

Comment: If you set it when you made your CopyObjectRequest, you should be able to compare the two for equality. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ultimately, if you're unsure, just test it. Use an file you don't care about.

Comment: I feel like I am missing some larger context, what is an ETag?

Comment: They explain it well in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591047/etag-definition-changed-in-amazon-s3

Answer (score 0):

AWS documentation says

> The source and destination ETag is identical for a successfully copied

[image]