# How to compare a file in your workspace with the one on git programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, git, compare, difference

I have an Eclipse workspace that I've cloned from Git and I need a list of files that have changed in my local compared to the ones on Git master.

I don't mean using `git diff`, I mean using Java programmatically using possible Java/Git APIs... So eventually a list/array of files that have changed should be returned.

I've seen some resources on servers other than Git, like here: [How to compare local file with Amazon s3 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591926/)

Comment: If you've got Eclipse, I presume you've also install egit.  So yes, you *should* use `git diff`!  And/or `git status`.  Why *wouldn't* you???

Comment: @paulsm4 No I'm making a plug in that will do stuff with the locally changed files... So I need a list of files in JAVA so I can tell my plugin to do stuff with those files! If that makes any sense

Comment: Yes, understood. You can easily create that list in Java by using [ProcessBuilder](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-exec-processbuilder-process-1) to invoke `git status`.

Comment: Ahh, with that I'm just worried if it would work well on windows. But I'll give that a try, I was hoping for more of a pure java answer I guess. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JGIT](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) API to compare the file between project files and a git branch/tag. It's pure java solution. All you need is install [EGIT](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/).

I ever wrote a Eclipse plugin [TeamFileList](https://github.com/beckyang/TeamFileList) for similar purpose. You can read the source of `com.beck.ep.team.git.GitListBuilder`, maybe it could help you.

Comment: That was my solution except the eclipse version I have to use to build the plugins is 3.7.2 (indigo) which isn't compatible with JGIT libraries.. do you know any work arounds?

Comment: For Eclipse 3.7.2, the latest EGIT is v2.3.1. You can find the link for **download p2 repository** in https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ