# Is there a way to do a checksum while transferring files from AWS S3 to Azure

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, checksum

I want to transfer files server-side from AZS S3 to Azure and do a checksum as well to verify if any file or packet has not been tampered with while transferring

Comment: I think Azure Blob Storage can give you the MD5 hash after upload from the blob's properties. You could maybe use that?

Comment: @juunas thanks, will check. But at first, I need to compute MD5 for files sitting on AWS S3, this will be gigs of files, i don't want to download them to compute MD5, will there be a way to do in S3

Comment: Seems the ETag on S3 _can_ be an MD5 hash: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41735844/1658906. That's a bit inconvenient :D

Comment: agree! I already checked that part. not that convenient. multipart upload support will be tricky. @junnas - Thanks a lot for your inputs