How to verify checksum of a multi-part uploaded S3 object during download?
When downloading using S3::GetObject API, how do I verify the integrity of the downloaded object that was uploaded using multipart APIs?
I understand, that one can download individual parts, verify them and then stitch them together, but I'm specifically looking for integrity validation at the client side after downloading the whole object using GetObject API.
For single part objects, the way I verify checksum is by specifying ChecksumMode='ENABLED' in the GetObject request. I don't think this will work on multipart.

Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58239738/22277802 this what I follow for validating (locally) a multipart S3 object.
